# Como usar PHPMailer en un theme de Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmailer, wordpress-theme

Estoy Diseñando un Theme de Wordpress, ya que diseñe el formulario de contacto no quiero valerme de un plugin, quiero hacerlo yo, estoy usando PHP Mailer, pero por alguna razón no me funciona.

**PD:** Quiero evitar la función *mail* de php por seguridad.

Agradecería la ayuda:

Este es mi código:

```
<?php
include("./PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php"); 
include("./PHPMailer/src/Exeption.php"); 
$respuesta;

$mail = new PHPMailer;
try {        
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
        $nombre = $_POST['nombreDePila']; 
        $correo = $_POST['correo'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $msj = $_POST['mensaje'];

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'mail.mailito.cl ';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'contacto@mailito.cl';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'contraseña';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        $mail->setFrom('contacto@sancor.cl', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress($correo, $nombre);     


        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
        $mail->Body    = '<h1>El cliente:'.$nombre.'</h1><br/><h3>Desde:'.$correo.'</h3><br/><h3>Telefono:'.$telefono.'</h3><p>'.$msj.'</p>';
        $mail->send();
        $respuesta = 'El mensaje fue enviado correctamente';
} catch (Exeption $e) {
        $respuesta = "Hubo un error al enviar el mensaje: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

echo $respuesta;
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el error que te arroja o a que te refieres con "por alguna razón no me funciona?

Answer (score 0):

Usa sendgrid fácil, rápido y eficiente:

Sube la librería al directorio de tu tema padre/hijo y mándala a llamar

```
require "includes/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php";
```

Añades el siguiente codigo para el envio

```
$body =  "Hello Man";

    $sendgrid = new SendGrid("miApiKey");
    $email    = new SendGrid\Email();

 
    $email->addTo("")
            ->setFrom("no-reply@correo.com.")
            ->setSubject("Subject")
            ->setHtml($body);

    $sendgrid->send($email);
```

Listo.